# How to save equations and formulas in Django Database?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, richtext

Working on a Project I need to save different articles which contains formulas and equations, Django core models support TextField which does not seems to save equations, they are all stored as plain text. I also tried adding [CKEDITOR](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#django-ckeditor) to my project but no chances on that too.

so the question is :

> How can I save texts containing formulas and equations in my SQLite DB?

Answer (score 0):

Have an editor that formats your Maths equation and save it as plain text. Then when you render your html template to see the maths equation, use something like http://asciimath.org/ to replace the plain text accordingly